# How to use pandas isin() with IF statement

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have a column(INT_STATUS) in a data frame(file1) and INT_STATUS has values from A to Z and 1 to 9. If INT_STATUS columns has values in this list ['B','C','F','H','P','R','T','X','Z','8','9'] then I want to create a new column "rcut" and give a value '01' **file1['rcut'] == '01'**.

Comment: You can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for this.  `file1['rcut'] = np.where(file1['INT_STATUS'].isin(['B','C','F','H','P','R','T','X','Z','8','9']), '01', '00')`

Comment: Can you give some example values for `file1['INT_STATUS']` since the name suggests values would not be letters.

Comment: @roganjosh Values are single alphabets or single digit numbers  ['B','C','F','H','P','R','T','X','Z','8','9']

Comment: @0x5453 their are few more condition, Like elfi statements. Please see the edit

Answer (score 3):

You can assign using loc

```
file1.loc[file1['INT_STATUS'].isin(l), 'rcut'] = '01'
```

Comment: Your answer helped me when I have a single if statement, but I have continuous if and elif statement, How can I apply for that situation.

Comment: Can you provide more details? What does the list look like for each condition?